# How to interpret/use VaR and Standard Deviation?

Tags: volatility, value-at-risk

The parametric VaR is defined as follows:

$$VaR=Z_a*Vol$$

- Is this the best way to interpret how much risk is being taken on for a particular asset?
- How does one interpret volatility on its own if its not converted into a percent figure?
- Therefore, wouldn't be better if sharp ratios were expressed in VaR's?
- I mean, what does it really mean if a Portfolio Manager is gaining 2% return for 1 unit of risk. What does 1 unit of risk mean?
- Shouldn't risk only be defined only in percentage terms -- having a hard time wrapping my head around this concept of volatility as a risk measure.
- **What do you guys think?**

Comment: My god... Just spend a bit of time to format your questions. It looks so much more understandable after what I just did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VaR is not a good measure of risk taking, in my opinion. It suffers from inherent faulty assumptions (check out VaR Wiki to start) and it omits many other important aspects of risk measurement.

When I evaluate an asset's risk and return I like to start looking at the following:

- Historical risk and returns of an asset. This leads to the Sharpe Ratio, though I prefer a slightly different ratio which does not penalize for excess performance to the upside (Sharpe Ratio does penalize)
- Expected returns and risk. Can I have confidence that historical risk and return figures are a reasonable predictor of future risk and return. If not then, is there a way to make adjustements? If not then I should not take into consideration historical risk and return values when evaluating future expected risk and returns.
- Drawdowns of an asset's return. Alongside the drawdown I want to know how long it took for the asset's subsequent returns to make it back to the pre-drawdown return.
- Correlation of the asset with other assets. Is the asset uncorrelated or potentially even negatively correlated with other assets?
- Contribution of the asset to the portfolio overall. Does the asset contribute to a lower portfolio risk and portfolio risk adjusted returns.

Regarding your points:

- "How does one interpret volatility on its own": It is a measure of variation around a certain mean, either historically around a historical mean or around expected value. Standard deviation is expressed in percentage terms if it is calculated using returns as input. If you calculate volatility on prices or other metrics then you need to convert to percentage figures.
- "What does the 1 unit of risk mean": The one unit of risk you refer to is in percentage terms so Sharpe Ratio expresses the excess return in percent per percent of risk. Its a very clear cut and simple way to comprehend risk, in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you for the response Freddy. My problem with volatility is simple, volatility can either be good or bad. If a stock,eg, breaks out to the upside and on several large range days, isn't that a large deviation from the mean and therefore would raise  volatility?? Yet, when I calculate volatility for stocks it only rises when the stock goes down not up -- this behaivor is really pecular. Not to mention, safe haven assets like the dollar (DXY) and the US Treasuries have higher volatility when their rallying!!! So how does one really compare volatility for different assets?

Comment: "Yet, when I calculate volatility for stocks it only rises when the stock goes down not up"  => May I ask what formula for vol. do you use?

Comment: Maybe not so peculiar if you consider the skew.  If you take implied volatility of out of the money calls on your asset, and subtract the implied volatility on equivalent out of the money puts, and do for each asset, i would hazard a guess that the signs corresponds to the direction of the vol shifts you're seeing.

Comment: @gabriel, I recommend you clearly differentiate between historical vols/standard deviations and implied volatilities, they are a different animal entirely. Implied vols can drop even when markets strongly bounce to the upside (especially after larger sell-offs) because of certain market perceptions whereas historical vols may not drop just because the sign of the underlying price momentum changes. You need to make clear which volatility measures you are talking about.

Comment: Freddy, I was referring to historical Vol but that shouldn't matter. Historical Vol and Implied Vol are very highly correlated, I think your splitting hairs at this point. The difference between the two is mean stationary -- your not going to see major trend divergences between historical vol and implied vol. Volatility eludes the heck out of me. Volatility doesn't rise for major moves on the upside but it does on moves to the downside. It's negatively correlated to risky assets and positively correlated to safe haven assets. How it became a risk measures blows my mind.

Comment: @gabriel, take a step back here, volatility like all asset classes goes through cycles. If you investigate long term you will see that your conclusions are incorrect for most part. But yes, big moves to the downside generally push up volatility by more than equal sized moves to the upside, thats why you observe a skew and not smile. Welcome to the real world my friend, people always take more extreme measures when you strip them off their clothes rather than showering them in wealth.

Comment: @gabriel, and implied vols and historical vols are entirely different animals altogether. Throwing them into the same pot shows that you have a lot of work in front of you. There is an entire species of vol traders who feed their families trading the divergences between the true relationship and what the market thinks of implied vol/hist.vol dynamics.

Comment: Freddy I've built several trading models based on the difference of actual & expected vol, I know they are different. I pointed out that while they are different, their difference is only mean stationary -- that's why spread traders love trading VOL because they have that mean reverting property. Those VOL traders your alluding too wouldn't have much to feed their family if it weren't for that property alone. Calling them "different animals" is a little further than I would have gone. I would have said more like: "same animal but different species".

Comment: I think your giving to much credit to investors/traders. I don't think implied vol is more forward looking than historical. If anything the historical vol-to-implied vol spread is a great excessive sentiment indicator.  Though your definitely right, the strike to vol chart on the SPY is skewed on the downside -- people are more willing to bid up calls to insure their portfolio. Though I am still puzzled as to why volatility moves differently for different assets and if its really correct to compare different assets on this one risk measure.

Comment: Markets have a tendency to rally for long periods of time, edging higher and higher, bit by bit, and correct in a short period. Maybe this is why volatility rises on the downside than on the upside. The skew you mentioned is also another good reason.

Comment: @gabriel, the difference between historical vols and implied vols BY FAR is not just mean stationarity. Divergences can move in completely unpredictable and far from mean reverting ways for so long and by that far that it will break any vol trader's bankroll by sticking out his neck by trying to bank on mean reversion. Look at the Porsche/VW story and what happened to Porsche options' implied vols vs historical vols. Your statement that historical and implied vols are highly correlated is like saying bananas and pine apples are highly correlated: Both are fruits....

Comment: @gabriel, sorry but could not help it: "implied vol is not more forward looking than historical"? Then what is implied vols in your opinion. Can you at least do a simple Google search in order to not make others chuckle? Implied volatility is the expectation of future realized volatility of an underlying asset. Which part of this definition is not forward looking and based on expectations? Then your comment about you admitting the existence of a higher put skew but then insisting that more people bid calls than puts for protection makes no sense.

Comment: You said you built trading models but you ask how to use VaR and standard deviation? Please get real for a second. I for my part am done with this discussion. You come across as a know-it-all...so I let you have it all. Happy New Year.